# Add active class when product is in wishlist at category page

Tags: magento2, wishlist, category-listing

I'm trying to add an active class when product is in wishlist.

I tried below code.

```
<?php 
    echo $_product->getId();
    $wishlist = $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getWishlistItemCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $_product->getId());
    print_r($wishlist->getData());

                    ?>

                 <div class="cdz-product-wishlist show-tooltip">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow() && $showCompareWishlist): ?>
                                <a href="#"
                                   class="action towishlist"
                                   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                   aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                   data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                   data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                   role="button">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif; ?> 
                    </div>
```

If I dump collection data then it returns me all products which are currently in wishlist but after I filter collection with `product_id` then it returns always first array.

**But product ID is printing correctly.**

Does anyone has idea what's issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
After spending an hour at last I ended up creating array of wishlist
products and match current product id using in_array.
```

Still if you have better solution I'm open for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');$(this).find('img').toggleClass('active');">
        <img class="wishlist-icon icon-empty <?php echo !$product['in_wishlist'] ? 'active' : ''; ?>" src="/image/wishlist-empty.svg">
        <img class="wishlist-icon icon-full <?php echo $product['in_wishlist'] ? 'active' : ''; ?>" src="/image/wishlist-full.svg">
      </a>
```